# Creating Event Bus in javaRx 2.0

Tags: android, rx-android

as in title I'm trying to create event bus for sharing multiple events bettwen fragments. I am using JavaRx 2 and Dagger 2 for injection. This is what I am trying to achieave: 
[Very interesting implementation](https://github.com/CharlesHarley/Example-Android-CustomDrawableStates/blob/master/src/com/charlesharley/example/android/customdrawablestates/HomeActivity.java)

This is how my event bus looks like:

```
    @MainScope
public class EventBus {

    @Inject
    public EventBus(){

    }

    private PublishSubject<Object> busSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public <T> Observable<T> register (Class<T> eventClass){

        return busSubject
                .filter(event -> event.getClass().equals(eventClass))
                .map(obj -> (T) obj);
    }


    public PublishSubject<Object> getBusSubject() {
        return busSubject;
    }

    public void post(Object event){
        busSubject.onNext(event);
    }
}
```

Then in mainPresenter I am postin simple class like this:

```
eventBus.post(id);
```

and in one of fragments where I have injected same instance of event Bus i subscribe for event:

```
Observer<IdEvent> observer = eventBus.register(IdEvent.class).observeOn(schedulersFacade.io()).subscribeOn(schedulersFacade.ui()).subscribeWith(new Observer<IdEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                System.out.println( );
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(IdEvent idEvent) {
                id = idEvent.getParsedId();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println( );
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println( );
            }
        });
```

On debug I see that post method is called so as onSubscribe observer method. The problem is that onNext method is never called. I am new in JavaRx and I cant figure solution of my problem, so I would be gratefull for any advices.

Comment: Registering based on class sounds very flimsy to me.  For one thing, if someone makes a subclass of your class, your register will fail to match on that subclass.  For a second, how many times do you want to send completely different data types down the same bus, but have no way of differentiating between them other than the type of data?  What if you want to send two different types of string events-  you wouldn't be able to differentiate. This seems like a classic case of overgeneralization here.  You'd be better off defining a message class to pass with a generic payload.

Comment: I think there will be about 5 different events (it may change in future) which I wanto to broadcast throught event bus. I want to be able to create multiple observers for different events in same presenters. Content of events may be very different, and I think that filtering events by className is more elegant than writing "case" blocks with "instanceof". But backing to problem, do you see anything that makes it not working?